# Access Term Topic Matrix generated by Gensim LDA

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I've trained an LDA model using gensim. I am under the impression that Lda reduces the data to two lower level matrices (ref: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/08/beginners-guide-to-topic-modeling-in-python/) but I cannot seem to figure out how to access the term-topic matrix. The only reference I could find in gensim's documentation is for the .get_topics() attribute, however the format it provides makes no sense to me.

It is easy enough to apply a transformation to retrieve the Document-topic matrix, like so:

```
doc_topic_matrix = lda_model[doc_term_matrix]
```

so I am hoping that there is a similarly functional method to generate the topic-term matrix.

Ideally, output should look like this:

```
         word1  word2  word3  word4  word5
topic_a   .12    .38    .07    .24    .19
topic_b   .41    .11    .04    .14    .30
```

Any thoughts on whether or not this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

It's easy, you could get it like this:

```
#get raw topic > word estimates
topics_terms = model.state.get_lambda() 

#convert estimates to probability (sum equals to 1 per topic)
topics_terms_proba = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x/x.sum(),1,topics_terms)

# find the right word based on column index
words = [model.id2word[i] for i in range(topics_terms_proba.shape[1])]

#put everything together
pd.DataFrame(topics_terms_proba,columns=words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned the appropriate method [`get_topics()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.get_topics).

Here is how you can interpret the results with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import LdaModel
from gensim.test.utils import common_dictionary, common_corpus

model = LdaModel(common_corpus, id2word=common_dictionary, num_topics=2)
pd.DataFrame(model.get_topics(), columns=model.id2word.values(), index=[f'topic {i}' for i in range(model.num_topics)])
```

The final result looks like:

[image: pandas dataframe]